# save list to CSV - python

Tags: csv, python-3.x, tkinter

I try to save my output as csv using the "import csv" and only get errors. Any reason why?

Since I can not make it run will it also notify if the file already exists?

Thanks a lot

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.filedialog import asksaveasfilename
from tkinter import ttk

import csv

def data():
  ...
  output= <class 'list'>  #just an example
  ...    

def savefile():
  name= asksaveasfilename()
  create = csv.writer(open(name, "wb"))
  create.writerow(output)
  for x in output:
      create.writerow(x)

root = Tk()
Mframe = ttk.Frame(root)
Mframe.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N, W, E, S))

bSave=ttk.Button(Mframe, text='Save File', command=savefile)
bSave.grid(column=1, row=0)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "... only get errors". What are the errors?

Comment: the error: "TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface"

Answer (score 0):

You are opening the file, but not closing it. A good practise is to use a with statement make sure you close it. By the way, I don't know how is the `output` list, but if it isn't a list of lists, it makes more sense to me to call `writerow` once.

Besides, make sure this list is also a global variable, otherwise it won't be available within the scope of `savefile`. However, global variables are not a very good solution, so consider to pass it as an argument to `savefile` or use a class to hold all this data:

```
def savefile():
    name = asksaveasfilename()
    with open(name, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        create = csv.writer(csvfile)
        create.writerow(output)
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed it to your suggested function and I get this error "TypeError: 'str' does not support the buffer interface". Can you please explain why?

Comment: @user2613527 In Python 3, binary mode does not work to write csv files. According to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#id2), you should use `open(name, 'w', newline='')` (I've updated the answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot. it is almost perfect. the str in the list are written in one row but in different cells and not row by row. I can not find out why?. The files are not saved with CSV extension, how can it be added using name=name+'.csv' will cause me problem will not work well if I need to overwrite a file.

Comment: Solved it (NL means new line):  name = asksaveasfilename() NL    output_file = open(name, 'w', newline='') NL     data = csv.writer(output_file) NL
   for row in output:   NL data.writerow([row])
NL
        output_file.close()